# Round up to next passing date in an interval

Tags: php, date, datetime, intervals

I have a `DateTime` object as start point and an object of `DateInterval` and another `DateTime` object. Now I need to find the next possible date passing in the interval started by the start date.

Values of both `DateTime` objects and the `DateInterval` are completely undefined. So the interval can contain something like 1 year or 365 days which have different meanings (leap year) and it can contain daylight saving or completely different timezones.

Can someone help me how to find the next date and time without iterating the hole interval?

I have the following rounding function doing iteration but this can be very slow on long iterations :(

```
function ceilDateTimeByInterval(DateTime $date, DateInterval $interval, DateTime $base) {
    if ($date < $base) {
        return null;
    }

    $result = clone $base;
    while ($date > $result) {
        $result = $result->add($interval);
    }

    $result = $result->setTimezone($date->getTimezone());
    return $result;
}
```

*Example:*

```
$base = new DateTime("2000-03-04 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin");
$date = new DateTime("2016-06-03 02:00:00 UTC");
$interval = new DateInterval('P5Y5M0D');
echo ceilDateTimeByInterval($date, $interval, $base)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
// = 2016-06-03 22:00:00 UTC

$base = new DateTime("1206-03-04 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin");
$date = new DateTime("2016-06-03 22:00:00 UTC");
$interval = new DateInterval('P10D');
echo ceilDateTimeByInterval($date, $interval, $base)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
// = 2016-06-04 22:00:00 UTC

$base = new DateTime("1206-03-04 00:00:00 Europe/Berlin");
$date = new DateTime("2016-06-03 22:45:34 UTC");
$interval = new DateInterval('P1WT12H12345S');
echo ceilDateTimeByInterval($date, $interval, $base)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e');
// = 2016-06-04 22:45:45 UTC
```

I can't find the right solution covering all edge cases :(

Comment: You need to better explain what you're looking for with an example and show what you've tried so far since this is not a code writing service.

Comment: @JohnConde I have added code and example

Comment: Thank you. If you can add a few more examples of different start dates and what your expect outcomes would be that will help make it clearer for me. I don't *think* what you're looking for is hard.

Comment: @JohnConde added 2 more examples - the function works well but can be slow - you can test your own examples here : http://3v4l.org/DS8tY

Comment: You could you DatePeriod object to ease up some of the iteration logic, but even there you would have to iterate over the entire DatePeriod object to get to the last date (it doesn't support direct index lookup).

Comment: @MikeBrant I know the `DatePeriod` but it would be the same -> iterating as long as the given date is greater or equal the current date in the interval - so no performance benefit. I personally think it should be possible with basic mathematics but I don't can find a working solution.

Comment: @MikeBrant DatePeriod can be changed to an array using iteratortoarray(), then you can take the last element without iterating over the whole array. That may be the route to the solution. I'm lying in bed writing this on an iPad, otherwise I'd try for an answer with working code. Maybe in the morning :)

Comment: @vascowhite That still will iterate through the whole object to populate the array when using `iterator_to_array()`, so still an O(n) operation.

Comment: @MikeBrant Yes, I was just thinking that, it may be faster than doing it in your own code though. I'll give it a bit more thought overnight, this is an interesting problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, with the way these classes work, I don't see a great solution to the problem.  I don't believe that there is some simple mathematical solution as OP is looking for though.  You could simply the code at least though using something like `$datetime_array = iterator_to_array(new DatePeriod($base, $interval, $date));`.  You could then easily `array_pop()` the last DateTime object out of that array.  Again, not likely to be much better from a performance standpoint, but is certainly cleaner code.

Comment: @MikeBrant Your solution is wrong. 1) if the date passes exactly into the interval the previous date will be used. 2) You creates an array for every interval entry which can be a lot resulting in much more slow down or memory limit error - see http://3v4l.org/tHWEF

Comment: @mabe.berlin As mentioned in earlier comments, it is understood that there is no way, given the available PHP classes to simply get the last DateTime from a period without iterating the entire period, so you should not expect any performance gain from the iterative method that you originally posted.  You are correct about end date in period not being included if it happens to lie exactly on the period.  You could conceivably shift the end date datetime object one second into the future to address this problem (i.e. `$date->modify('+1 second');`)